# qmake .pro file could not be parsed

Tags: qt5, qmake

I'm running OS X Mavericks and trying to convert a Qt4 application to Qt5. I've also never compiled the application on this machine before. I have Qt 5.1.* installed on this machine, which parses the file just fine. As soon as I switch over to my Qt 5.2.0 kit and look at the run settings, underneath my "Run configuration" there's a warning: "The .pro file '.pro' could not be parsed.".

I've looked at other solutions on SO and the qt-project website -- none of which have helped. My Qt 5.2.0 kit *is* a manually-added kit since I installed it using Homebrew.

Here is a screenshot of my settings:

[image: Qt 5.2.0 settings]

Note that if I run qmake (/usr/local/opt/qt5/bin/qmake) in the project directory, no errors are output.

Here is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core widgets concurrent

TARGET = Up
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainForm.cpp \
    AboutForm.cpp \
    progressdialog.cpp

HEADERS  += MainForm.h \
    AboutForm.h \
    progressdialog.h

FORMS    += MainForm.ui \
    AboutForm.ui \
    progressdialog.ui

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../FATX/FATX

RESOURCES += \
    MainForm.qrc

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../FATX-BUILD-OSX/debug/ -lFATX

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../FATX-BUILD-OSX/debug
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../FATX-BUILD-OSX/debug

    macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../FATX-BUILD-OSX/debug/libFATX.a
} else {
    macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../FATX-OSX/release/ -lFATX

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../FATX-BUILD-OSX/release
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../FATX-BUILD-OSX/release

    macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../FATX-OSX/release/libFATX.a
}

cache()
```

Comment: Which QtCreator version is that?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I just noticed it's 2.8.1. I'll install 3.0 and see if it behaves any nicer.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld that fixed my issue! If you would like to reply with an answer I'd be glad to mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to update Qt Creator to Qt 3.0.0.